# $R$ is a ring and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Prove...

Tags: abstract-algebra

$R$ is a ring and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$.

Let $(r,s\in R; rRs\subseteq P\Longrightarrow r\in P \vee s\in P)$. 

Prove that if $\langle r\rangle, \langle s\rangle$ are real ideals of $R$, such that $\langle r\rangle \langle s\rangle \subseteq P$, then $r\in P \vee s\in P$.

Comment: What are "real ideals"?

Comment: @lhf The real ideal of a ring is not equal to the ring.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to prove that $<r> \subseteq P $ or $<s> \subseteq P$ , otherwise it's easy.

Suppose $<r> \not\subseteq P $ and  $<s> \not\subseteq P $.

So in particular there exist $a \in <r> $ and $b \in <s> $ such that $$a \not\in P $$ and $$b \not\in P$$ But $ab \in <r><s> \subseteq P $, and this implies by definition of prime ideal that $a \in P $ or $b \in P $.